# Preventing IE 8 ctrl+a from selecting everything on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to allow a user to select all the items with ctrl+a in a multiple select using JQuery. I have the code that will select all the options, however, IE and FF are also selecting all the controls on the page, how do I prevent this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dropdown").keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey) {
            if (e.keyCode == 65 || e.keyCode == 97) {
                e.stopPropagation();                    
                $("#dropdown").children().each(function() {
                    $(this).attr("selected","selected");
                });



            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That's what ctrl-a does?!

Comment: What does the code look like?

Comment: I am not trying to prevent the user from ctrl+A. I have a dropdown that I want all the options selected. Not every control on the page.

Comment: Provide another checkbox which will activate all other entries. Don't try to overwrite [Ctrl]+[A]!

Comment: @Dylan you won't be able to override native software's interpretation of CTRL+A without developing add-on or plug-in. JavaScript can't do it.

Comment: @liam ctrl+A does not select everything in Chrome.

Comment: @SetSailMedia good point. This is not possible as shortcuts are controlled by the browser, a level above any javascript implementation. Take the `CTRL+S` shortcut in JSFiddle - it doesn't work as the browser thinks you're trying to save the current page to your local machine.

Comment: No, but it does in other browsers. @SetSailMedia, has it. You can't tell a browser what Ctrl-A does. It's the browsers perogative to do what it wants with that command.

Comment: @Dylan just because you can do it in chrome doesn't necessarily mean other browsers will allow you to do it. If you can't stop it with `return false`, you can't stop it.

Comment: I've just tried hitting Ctrl-A in Chrome and IE. They both select all values. This is native browser behavior. If you really want to add that feature yourself, then provide another control (button or checkbox) which will activate all entries.

Comment: Instead of trying to override a common keyboard shortcut, maybe use another? Imagine trying to override `ctrl+alt+del` in the browser :P, this isn't as dramatic as that but I hope you get my point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

preventDefault() will allow the user to ctrl+a, selecting all options w/o selecting all the controls on the page for IE 8 and FF.